# substr concatenating array elements c++

Tags: c++, arrays, substr

I am building a function extract the last names from an array and print the name to screen. I have been able to extract the first last name in the array but then the output concatenates the first index's first name with the following index positions last name. Below is my code, thanks for the help!

```
{

    stringstream ss; 
    string name;


    for(int i=0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        ss << first[i];
        ss >> name;
        int pos = name.find(",");
        cout << pos;
        string last = name.substr(0,pos);
        cout << "\"" << last << "\"" << endl;


    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: You probably want to check if `find()` returned something different from `std::string::npos` and use `string last = name.substr(0,pos - 1);`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to help. Subtracting 1 from the position is not going to help, as it will just remove one character from the output. I am trying to figure out why the names from the array are concatenating with strings that are on separate indexs of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
int main()
{
   string name = "asd,kkaa";
   int pos = name.find(",");
   if(string::npos != pos)
   {
      string part1 = name.substr(0,pos);
      string part2 = name.substr(pos+1);
      cout << "\"" << part1 << "\"" << endl;
      cout << "\"" << part2 << "\"" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
// output:
// "asd" 
// "kkaa"
```

I think it's OK, so could give us more your input value?

Comment: thanks Ill give this a test, input values are in the format: Montana, Tony

Comment: No Its still concatenating different array indexs, example: Tony, Montana -- Dean, James -- is becoming "Dean" --- "Montana" --- "TonyDean"

Comment: could you tell us your array info [I mean exact structure] and what kind you want to pass to the function, and what's result you want at the end?

Comment: Thanks for your help but Josh below was able to tell me what was wrong, just needed to clear the stream by adding ss.str("") and ss.clear() after my streams.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the way you are using string streams.

Every time you read a new name from the array, you're adding it to the output buffer. You then read the next word from the buffer so therefore, you never skip the first name . For what it looks like you're doing, you can just eliminate the string stream all together and just stick to the standard input and output (cin/cout). Otherwise, clear the buffer everytime you read in a new string (ss.clear());

```
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){
        int pos = elements[i].find(",");
        cout << "\"" << elements[i].substr(0,pos) << "\"" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: _`cout << "\" << elements[i].substr(0,pos)<<"\n";`_ Uhm, what please??